# Как реализовать запрос разрешений единожды при запуске Android APK?

Tags: android, android-sdk

В общем, есть приложение, оно может получать и отправлять смс, а также принимать и отклонять звонки. Можно ли сделать запрос необходимых решений при первом запуске, а не каждый раз когда приложение отправляет смс или отклоняет звонок? Дальше приложение автоматически запускается уже имея все необходимые разрешения, такая задача.

Я пробовал просто указывать target sdk 21, ошибка, мол только 31. Это вроде как можно обойти, если приложение будет использоваться ограниченным кругом людей и не будет выложено в google play. Я был рад если бы подсказали кто знает как это обходить

Answer (score 1):

Крч, лучшей ответ который я нашел на текущий момент - это либо вовсе не запрашивать никаких разрешения и проставить их вручную через настройки, либо использовать чекбокс - "Больше не спрашивать" и нажать на "разрешить".

Что касается целевой SDK версии в build.gradle - то можно оставить 31 версию как целевую, на выше упомянутых вариантах это никак не отразится насколько я понял.